# How to understand pointer 'next' in a linked list structure?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
struct Node
{
   int a;
   struct Node *next;
};
```

How will `next` address point dynamically? I read `malloc` returns address value — is that right?
Please explain `struct Node *next`.  Is this the default way of declaring a pointer in a struct?

Comment: This is the standard way of declaring a linked list or many other data structures. Read any data structures text book for detailed information.

Comment: did malloc returns void pointer???

Comment: @Sudheergv Yes `malloc` retrun `void *` .

Comment: It's not `Struct`, it's `struct`. Your code won't compile. (Unless you defined Struct as struct). Please post valid code.

Comment: Can we collect that Void*

Comment: @Sudheergv I don't understand what you meant by _collect_ , but allocating memory to pointer using `malloc` , means that pointer points to that allocated block of memory on heap .

Comment: @V.Kravchenko ohh that's mistake,I'll correct, Thank you :-)

Comment: @ameyCU , I mean to store that returned void* value to the current node ,So that it can link to next node.

Comment: @Sudheergv In that case you would point the `next` of the current node to the following next node in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your declaration is correct. To understand it, see it this way. When the compiler wants to know what kind of pointer it should compile the strcut's next field. The declaration type you gave is used. Since the compiler already parses the structure before coming to this line. It understands that the next pointer type is also of same structure type. I hope this helps in your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this declaration

```
struct Node
{
   int a;
   struct Node *next;
};
```

then you can define it like so:

```
struct Node node = {1, 0};
```

or

```
struct Node *node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

---

When you want to attach a node to the `next` member then you can like so for example:

```
node.next = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

or

```
node->next = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

---

Example experiment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct Node
    {
       int a;
       struct Node *next;
    };

    struct Node node1;
    struct Node *node2 = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 

    node1.a = 1;
    node2->a = 2;
    node1.next = node2;
    node2->next = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node2->next->a = 3;

    printf("node1.a = %d, node1->next->a node2->a = %d, node2->next->a = %d\n", node1.a, node2->a, node2->next->a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start points to the top of the list and is available globally to your program. Whereas next just keeps track of the next item, and is available when referring to a specific 'node'. See this diagram it may help you understand with a visual!

link internally tracks the following item which keeps track of where the next component is as it is not necessarily contiguous the way arrays are.

```
+------+     +------+     +------+
| data |     | data |     | data |
+------+     +------+     +------+
| next |---->| next |---->| next |----> NULL
+------+     +------+     +------+
   ^
   |
 START (Keep track of the whole list.)
```

Hope that helps clarify.